# Написание функций вычисления характеристик геометрических фигур в языке Си

Tags: c, функции

Всем привет!
Сейчас я решаю задачу: вычисление характеристик геометрических фигур за пределами функции main c использованием самописных функций.
По условиям задачи необходимо вычислить характеристики следующих фигур:

```
1. Area of circle;          // площадь окружности

2. Cricumference of circle; // длина окружности

3. Area of square;          // площадь квадрата

4. Area of rectangle        // площадь прямоугольника
```

Мой код:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

const double PI = 3.1419526;

double area_of_circle(double diameter1 = 5.6);
double circumference(double radius = 7.0);
double area_of_square(double side_of_square = 10.0);
double area_of_rectangle(double length = 12,  double width = 77);

int main(void)
{

 /* вычисление площади окружности */

    printf("The diameter of the circle is %.1f\nPI is %.5f\narea of the circle %.2f\n\n", diameter1,area_of_circle);

    /* вычисление длины окружности */

    printf("The diameter of the circle is %.1f\nPI is %.5f\ncircumference of the circle %.2f\n\n", diameter,circumference);

    /* вычисление площади квадрата */

    printf("The area of the square is %.1f\nthe side of the square %.2f\n\n",
           area_of_square,side_of_square);

    /* вычисление площади прямоугольника */

    printf("The area of the rectangle is %.1f\nthe length is %.2f\nthe width is %.2f\n", area_of_rectangle, length, width);

    return 0;
}

    double area_of_circle(double diameter)
    {
        return (PI*pow(diameter, 2.0))/4;
    }

    double circumference(double radius)
    {
        return 2*PI*radius;
    }

    double area_of_square(double side_of_square)
    {
        return pow(side_of_square, 2);
    }

    double area_of_rectangle(double length,  double width)
    {
        return length*width;
    }
```

Я только начинаю изучать язык Си.Подскажите мне пожалуйста,где я мог допустить ошибку.

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («**почему этот код не работает?**») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения **прямо в вопросе**. Вопросы **без явного описания проблемы** бесполезны для остальных посетителей. См. [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Есть предположение,что написал все правильно,но ошибся с функцией printf

Comment: Кроме того у меня есть понимание,что я ошибся в семантике,а не в синтаксисе.

Answer (score 2):

Передавайте в `printf` не сами функции, а результаты их работы. Типа, не

```
printf("The diameter of the circle is %.1f\nPI is %.5f\narea of the circle %.2f\n\n",
       diameter1,area_of_circle);
```

а

```
printf("The diameter of the circle is %.1f\nPI is %.5f\narea of the circle %.2f\n\n",
       diameter1,area_of_circle(diameter1));
```

Где, само собой, `diameter1` — переменная, которая до вывода должна быть объявлена как имеющая тип `double`, а потом считанная...

И поскольку у вас используется тип `double`, то не `%.1f` и т.п., а `%.1lf`...